# Translating SQL Functions in Criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to reproduce this sql query into a hibernate criteria query how can I achieve tha.

```
SELECT * 
FROM PERSON
WHERE 
    BIRTH_DATE IS NOT NULL 
    AND (YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(BIRTH_DATE)) in(6,18,26)
ORDER BY 
    MONTH(BIRTH_DATE) ASC, 
    DAY(BIRTH_DATE) ASC
```

Globally what I want is to get everybody in age of 6,18 and 26 years old ordered only by the month and the day not the year to have a list of future anniversaries.

In fact my problem in this situation is that I don't know how I can use the sql functions in criteria I know how criteria works but this query is quite tricky I don't have any idea how to reproduce it in criteria =/

```
Criteria criteriaBirthDates = his.getSession().createCriteria(Person.class);
criteriaBirthDates.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("birthdate"));
criteriaBirthDates.addOrder(Order.asc("month(birthdate)"));
criteriaBirthDates.addOrder(Order.asc("day(birthdate)"));
return criteriaBirthDates.list();
```

Many thanks!

Comment: In fact my problem in this situation is that I don't know how I can use the sql functions in criteria I know how criteria works but this query is quite tricky I don't have any idea how to reproduce it in criteria =/

Comment: All right I just have mentionned it now could you help me please...?

Answer (score 0):

So I went to the official hibernate forum and here was the answer :

> Hi akyo
>
> Sorry, it's impossible be be done by QBC, as an old functionality, QBC
>   will not be improved in the future.
>
> Please use the new functionality "JPA Criteria to do it", For example
>
> Code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteraBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> cq = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> person = cb.from(Person.class);
cq
.where(
    cb.isNotNull(person.get(Person_.birthDate),
    cb.in(
        cb.diff(
            cb.function("YEAR", cb.function("GETDATE")),
            cb.function("YEAR", person.get(Person_.birthDate))
        )
    )
    .value(6, 8, 26)
)
.orderBy(
    cb.asc(cb.function("MONTH", person.get(Person_.birthDate))),
    cb.asc(cb.function("DAY", person.get(Person_.birthDate)))
);
```

Et voilà!